# Magento 2.2.6 issue: php bin/magento catalog:image:resize

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

When run command `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`, it stops after few images and shows error.

How fix this?

[image]

I tried manually reupload images to this folder after this problem.

[image]

Comment: Check file/folder permission at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/images/product/placeholder`

Comment: I tried change folder placeholder permission 755 to 777 but it is same problem.

Comment: have you fix this error? if yes please add solution.  I have same issue.

Comment: What is the solution for this?
Even i am facing the same problem

Comment: i am facing same issue,is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I hate magneto. Another bug
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22808

Comment: The only way I managed to fix this was going into m2 admin (could not find where product images are set in the database itself, probably spread over 20 tables..) and deleting the missing image from the product edit page. Obviously this is not a good solution especially if you do not know to which product the missing image(s) belong to.

Answer (score 3):

Peter,

It seems you are missing swatch image place holder.

Either upload it from the backend or upload manually to below file path

/home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/images/product/placeholder

name should be swatch_image.jpg only.

Comment: You are reading my message? "I tried manually reupload images to this folder after this problem." Check second image.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the path in my error message looks strange and yours looks the same with slightly different folder names.

`File '/var/www/magento/pub/media/var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/images/product/placeholder/swatch_image.jpg' does not exist.`

The second half of that path is real and the image is there:

`var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/images/product/placeholder/swatch_image.jpg`

However the error implies that it's prepending that location with `var/www/magento/pub/media/`

Is that intentionally like that or is this problem related to where it's looking for the image?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: how is this an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same problem and I can confirm that the script is prepending [webroot]/pub/media/ to the path of the image it wants to resize and therefore can't find it.

Thus, it's not a solution to add an image to that path since the path does not exist.

**Anyway, you can still just ignore the error and skip the batch resizing.** The result will be the same as after emptying the image cache from the admin interface.

**In consequence, resized images will be generated on demand for each product when the product (detail page) is viewed by a frontend user for the first time.** This will slow down performance for the first impression of each product's detail page. Apart from that, there should not be any negative consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Please Read 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.6CE.html
The catalog:image:resize command execution time has been reduced by up to 90% in the release. However, this improvement necessitates these additional steps after upgrading your Magento instance to 2.2.6:

Remove pub/media/catalog/product/cache . (Removing this folder frees up space.)

Run bin/magento catalog:image:resize to generate a new image cache. (This step is necessary because we’ve changed the path to cached images and must remove the previously cached images.)

Comment: I tried remove folder cache and var content but still same issue.

Comment: I solved issue removing placeholder folder content files swatch_image.jpg, image.jpg, small_image.jpg and thumbnail.jpg. When restore back to placeholder content files it show same error. But problem is still why it show error for placeholder content files?

Comment: Because such condition are there  in to code that's why.

Comment: it's not working still.

Answer (score 1):

Some Images could not be resized. See log file for details

Example:

```
5781-R101.png  do not work   ABCDEFG.jpg work
08985-AA01.jpg do not work   ABCDEFH.jpg work
```

I did not change much on picture only name changes

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uploading the placeholder images in the backend.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-image-placeholders.html

The cause of the problem maybe was that we recently moved the site to a new server with new paths.